# Rotação em determinadas telas

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Como faço para definir somente uma `UIViewController` estar habilitada em rotação?

O cenário é o seguinte:

> Eu possuo 5 telas, e em todas elas eu devo habilitar somente o modo
>   retrato. Porém eu possuo uma sexta tela, e esta deve estar habilitado
>   os modos em paisagem.

Obs: Atualmente as configurações do meu projeto está para aceitar somente o modo `portrait`.

Comment: Queres que esta suporte todas as orientações ou apenas "paisagem"?

Comment: Todas as orientações

Answer (score 1):

Faça o seguinte:

crie um projeto no `Xcode 6.1.1` com o template `Tabbed Application` pois é mais rápido de desenvolver e demostrar a funcionalidade. Eu fiz em Swift mas deve ser igual em Objective-C

Você terá o `Tab Bar Controller` e duas views relacionadas sendo:
`FirstViewController` e a `SecondViewController`

Numa das views (`FirstViewController` por exemplo) faça como na figura abaixo. A outra deixe tudo no Default (Orientation: inferred, etc.). Para min só funcionou a orientação fixa Portrait na View `FirstView` quando desmarquei a opção `Resize view from NIB`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É isso ! Funciona : apenas a `FirstView` fica com Orientação fixa. A `SecondView` permite a troca de orientação se adequando as novas dimensões.

> Você pode baixar o projeto em https://github.com/joao-parana/only-one-can-landscape.

Answer (score 0):

1. Habilite nas configurações do projeto todas as orientações que você vai precisar. (No seu caso habilita tudo, pelo que entendi.)
2. Em **todos** `UIViewController`'s do seu projeto implemente o método `supportedInterfaceOrientations` retornando a configuração desejada.

   Exemplo no *controller* que vai suportar todas retorna
   `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` nos outros retorna
   `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`
3. Se estiver utilizando Storyboard deixe tudo marcado como `inferred` em `Simulated Metrics`

Answer (score -2):

Olá, no AppDelegate.h adicione

```
@property (nonatomic , assign) bool blockRotation;
```

e no AppDelegate.m

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application       supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if (self.blockRotation) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

E nas views que você quer desabilitar a rotação, basta adicionar

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate* shared=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    shared.allowRotation=YES;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
  AppDelegate* shared=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  shared.allowRotation=NO;

  }
```

Outro modo, é adicionar em cada view a verificação

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296399/ios-how-to-stop-view-rotate